I don't really understand session response in next-auth v5
I can´t access the data of my session inside the APIs
When I access the session normally outside of an API with
const session = await auth();

It returns me the session normally, but when i try to do that inside an API it returns me a response with an object with different propperties, so I cant access my user or anything. I hope this is understandable. If anyone knows about this weird behaviour, I would very much like advice on itenter image description here
